# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, pyspark

I am trying to pass a numpy array to a python function like below:

```
polygonArr = np.empty([3,2])
for i in range(0,3):
    polygonArr[i,0]=someValue
    polygonArr[i,1]=somevalue

polygonArrObj = np.asarray(polygonArr)

point_inside_polygon_ = udf(point_inside_polygon,BooleanType())

df1=df.where(point_inside_polygon_(df_gst['lattd_c'],df_gst['lngtd_c'],polygonArrObj))
```

df1 and df are spark dataframes

The function point_in_a_polygon_ needs an array.
But when I try to run it I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Do I need to change the numpy.ndarray to a normal array object, or I am missing something else? If I need to change to an array object, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Spark SQL UDF can take only columns or columns literals as an argument. It cannot take arbitrary Python object. Since there is not literal syntax for `VectorUDT` you'll have to pass `polygonArrObj` using closure:

```
def inside_polygon_(polygon):
    return udf(
        lambda lat, long: point_inside_polygon(lat, long, polygon),
        BooleanType()
    )

df.where(inside_polygon_(polygonArrObj)('lattd_c', 'lngtd_c'))
```